# Chef with Ohai plugins instead bash scripting

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In Chef I need to discover all running instances. For this i have created ruby block with bash script and that is working. However i was told that this work should be done with Ohai plugins without using shell scripting. Can someone give few hints how to implement this with Ruby and Ohai plugins because i have no knowledge about this. Below you can see bash script part.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $8}')
if [ -z "${result}" ] ; then
  echo "no_instances"
  exit 0
else
  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  for i in $(ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep);  do
    if [[ $(`echo $i|awk '{print $8}'` --version) == *"MariaDB"* ]]; then
      instance=$(echo $i|awk '{print $1}')
      getent passwd ${instance} |cut -d':' -f1
    fi
  done
  IFS=$OIFS
fi
```

---

I have edited my code in ruby but I doubt that in this way i can add it under Ohai plugin. Can you suggest?

```
result = `ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $1 , $8}'`
if result and result != ""
  result.each do |line|
    cmd = `#{line.split(" ")[1].chomp + " --version\n"}`
    if cmd != "" and cmd.include? "MariaDB"
      print `getent passwd #{line.split("/")[0]} |cut -d':' -f1`
    end
  end
else
  exit
end
```

---

I tried to write Ohai plugin it would be great if someone can look into this and suggest what is wrong or how to tune it:

```
Ohai.plugin(:Mariadb_instances) do

  provides 'Mariadb_instances'

  collect_data(:linux) do
    Mariadb_instances Mash.new
    result = `ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $1 , $8}'`
    if result and result != ""
      result.each do |entry|
        cmd = `#{entry.split(" ")[1].chomp + " --version\n"}`
        if cmd != "" and cmd.include? "MariaDB"
         Mariadb_instances[`hostname`] = `getent passwd #{entry.split("/")[0]} |cut -d':' -f1`  # [`hostname`] can be removed if chef provides it by default
        end
      end
    else
      Chef::Log.debug("MariaDB is not found")
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: This question is too general unless you’re just asking us to literally write the whole thing for you.

Comment: I need deeper explanation how to set up my bash script in Ohai plugin, because from documentation there is only syntax for Ohai plugin. I see that i can collect OS parameters here but dont know how to make a way to only one running process that i need from all.

Comment: The two have nothing to do with each other. You need rewrite your code in Ruby.

Comment: Hello, maybe you can look ant suggest what is wrong and how to tune it. I wrote it but i doubt that it will work.